# Parsing with jsoup throws error (NetworkOnMainThreadException)

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I downloaded the jsoup library **jsoup-1.7.1.jar core** and imported it to my project using the **Project -> Properties->Java Build Path -> Add external Jars** and I pasted the library file to my libs folder. However there seems to be some problem about importing the Jsoup library to my project. When I run my app, upon launching I get this error.

```
12-26 22:59:24.133: E/AndroidRuntime(6710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 22:59:24.133: E/AndroidRuntime(6710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsouptest/com.example.jsouptest.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

After searching and asking I found out that eclipse sees the jsoup.jar, but unable to package it to APK file for the app to run. I tried to organize Imports by pressing **Shift+Alt+O** and I would get the same error. At this point, I am unsure about what is wrong and have no idea how to fix it. I have only hope someone will lead me toward the solution. Appreciate your time!

This is my code:

```
package com.example.jsouptest;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Document doc;
         try {
             doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
             String title = doc.title();
          System.out.print(title);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Which has nothing to do with your jar working properly or not.

The Exception is thrown by the new versions of Android so that you don't lock the UI Thread (which is the main Thread) doing network operations.

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (simple explanation about what each part of the AsyncTask does can be found [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/))or another [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) for network stuff. An Asynctask is easier to work with if you need to update the UI once the background work completes.

An example of an AsyncTask with your code base can be:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String title ="";
    Document doc;
    try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
      title = doc.title();
      System.out.print(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return title;   
  } 


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {        
    //if you had a ui element, you could display the title
    ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.myTextView)).setText (result);
  }
}
```

I assume:

- The task is an **inner** class in your Activity.
- You are forwarding the title gotten to a UI Element (eg a `TextView`) since that's what AsyncTasks are usually used for.

To call the AsyncTask, put this after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Comment: Exactly right. @Questions, you can use my DataLoader for this as well: https://github.com/christopherperry/dataloader (shameless plug)

Comment: I updated my question and add my source code. Can you show me how you would use the AsyncTask here? Thanks!

Comment: @Thanks, there is a problem with the code I think. I added an extra picture.

Comment: @Questions that line wasn't needed. I took the example code I linked and modified it, and overlooked that.

Comment: @A--C You are a hero. I Appreciate your help so much.

Answer (score -2):

Import these library `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` and `android.os.StrictMode` and use below strict mode

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Also add this line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```