# App works in Emulator, but not on a real device

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, jsoup

Currently following this tutorial [Android XML Adventure – Parsing HTML using JSoup](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/), app works in Emulator, but display Error in TextView on device.

I have copy and paste jsoup-1.7.2.jar into libs, set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml and set TextView `android:id="@+id/tv"` . And this is what my [Project Explorer](http://s24.postimg.org/6l1vveiud/eclipse.png) looks like.

Here is the JsoupActivity.java

```
package com.jsoupstudyactivity;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Menu;

public class JSoupActivity extends Activity {

    // blog url
    static final String BLOG_URL = "http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         // process
        try {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(getBlogStats());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error");
        }
    }

    protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        // get html document structure
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
        // selector query
        Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#blog-stats-2 ul li");
        // check results
        if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
            // get value
            result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
        }

        // return
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jsoup, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (block-stats-2 instead of block-stats)

```
Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#blog-stats-2 ul li");
```

You should get 657,462 View.

Comment: This will match div id starting with blog-stats
`Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div[id^=blog-stats] ul li");`

Comment: The method getBlogstats() should not be ran in the main thread: try using an AsyncTask. Print the stack trace in the catch block. You may be getting a network on main thread exception which will be fixed by moving the getBlockStats method to a different thread.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247339/parsing-with-jsoup-throws-error-networkonmainthreadexception?rq=1

Comment: I have implement AsyncTask, and all is working fine...many thanks.