# Error in parsing HTML table and converting to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, jsoup

```
doc = Jsoup.parse("<table><tr><td>Phone No</td><td>Officers</td></tr><tr><td>123456789</td><td>Csa</td></tr></table>");
try {
    for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            String PhoneNo = tds.get(0).text();
            String Officers = tds.get(1).text();
            jsonObject.put("Phone No", PhoneNo);
            jsonObject.put("Officers", Officers);
        }
        list.put(jsonObject);
    }
} catch ( JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this code works perfectly but when i try following code

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, then i follow the following solution "[Parsing with jsoup throws error (NetworkOnMainThreadException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247339/parsing-with-jsoup-throws-error-networkonmainthreadexception)" and put my code in `AsyncTask` it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

Here is Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1    Process: com.rams.amar.information, PID: 12076    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.rams.amar.information.activities.ContactsActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(ContactsActivity.java:58)
    at com.rams.amar.information.activities.ContactsActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(ContactsActivity.java:41)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is whole code:  ContactsActivity.java

```
package com.rams.a.information.activities;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.rams.a.information.R;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url="http://www.uok.ac.in/contactus.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nav_contacts);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.setTitle("Contacts");
        MyTask mT = new MyTask();
        mT.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if((item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home))
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        Document doc;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");
                        String PhoneNo = tds.get(0).text();
                        String Officers = tds.get(1).text();
                        jsonObject.put("Phone No", PhoneNo);
                        jsonObject.put("Officers", Officers);
                    }
                    list.put(jsonObject);
                }
            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return list.toString();//stringArray.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView3)).setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "An error occurred"? What error? Stacktrace, please?

Comment: @cricjet_007 check now

Comment: Okay, and which part of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` isn't clear? What if `tds.size() == 1`, then `tds.get(1)` will never work

Comment: i'm not putting it in any array, instead trying to just show in `TextView`,  as i already told above code works perfectly and shows the JSON Array @cricjet_007

Comment: Well, clearly the code doesn't work, otherwise, you wouldn't get an exception. `ContactsActivity.java:112` **does** have some ArrayList.

Comment: Yup, something is wrong, but not getting that

Comment: Can you show your code as a [mcve]? You said you have no arraylist, but the stacktrace suggests otherwise...

Comment: May be its because of `JSONArray list = new JSONArray();`

Comment: Just [edit] your question with the whole `ContactsActivity.java` code, please. Or tell us what is on Line 112 of that class. It's some `get(1)` method on a collection with only one element, not two, and that is what the error says

Comment: @cricjet_007 check now added whole `ContactsActivity.java` code

Comment: You don't have 112 lines of code there, so whatever stacktrace you have provided, it does not match the code you provided.

Comment: Okay, like I said earlier... `tds.get(1)` is going to error when `tds.size() == 1`. You can debug your own code to see `doc.select("table")` probably doesn't always have tables with two columns.

Comment: @cricjet_007 thanks got the error, `tds: size=2` but at a point it become `tds: size=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
     for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
         for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
             Elements tds = row.select("td");
             if(tds.size()==1){continue;} else{
                 String PhoneNo = tds.get(0).text();
                 String Officers = tds.get(1).text();
                 jsonObject.put("Phone No", PhoneNo);
                 jsonObject.put("Officers", Officers);
             }
             list.put(jsonObject);
         }
     }
} catch ( JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This Code Works Perfectly.

Comment: It was generating same data for whole list and another thing on my side, if I use `if(tds.size()==1){ }` insert one empty row in list instead of skipping that record where `if(tds.size()==1){continue;}` works. But you gave me basic idea and i'm really thankful for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your HTML table data doesn't always have two columns.

Try adding an if-statement.

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        if (tds.size() >= 2) {  // see here                
            jsonObject.put("Phone No", tds.get(0).text());
            jsonObject.put("Officers", tds.get(1).text());

            list.put(jsonObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to create `new JSONObject` within the loop, by the way

Comment: yup its generating but it skips one "Phone No", i.e. there is a person holding two nums

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any additional tag like doctype or xml declaration etc coming in the content prior to the table  body.

Answer (score -1):

Write down below code in your activity onCreate()

```
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Just because you can do this doesn't mean you ever should.